# In rails, can you have an association between two models where the primary_key and foreign_key are of different data types?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, activerecord, foreign-keys, primary-key

Is the following kosher?

```
schema.rb
  users
    id:int (autoincr.)
    uid:string <----------------
    ...

  fb_friends
    id:int (autoincr.)
    uid:int <-------------------
    friend_uid:int
    ...

user.rb
   has_many :fb_friends, :primary_key => "uid", :foreign_key => "uid"
```

Note that the keys that tie a "user" and their "fb_friends" together are of different data types (string and int). In an ideal world, I probably wouldn't do this, but given the current system architecture, this seems to be the solution that would work best.

But is this okay to do / will it work without snafoos?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the DB engine you're using, e.g, for mysql =>

> Corresponding columns in the foreign
>   key and the referenced key must have
>   similar internal data types inside
>   InnoDB so that they can be compared
>   without a type conversion. The size
>   and sign of integer types must be the
>   same. The length of string types need
>   not be the same. For nonbinary
>   (character) string columns, the
>   character set and collation must be
>   the same.

More info [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html), Anyways, I won't say it's a good practice to compare fields of different types :(.

Hope it helps you!

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if it works, but I wouldn't recommend it if you have the option to change it. It's really easy to change a column type in a Rails migration:

```
change_column :users, :uuid, :integer
```